# How can I update a calendar event using Microsoft Graph

Tags: events, graph, outlook, calendar

I have managed to add new events in my Outlook calendar, but updating or deleting is not working. I think I do not use a correct key. From the API description I understood that the iCalUId - generated while creating a new event and returned in the response message - is the unique identifier of a calendar event, so I use this one.

JavaScript:

```
client
 .api('/me/calendars/xxxxxxxx (=my Calendar ID)/events/')
 .update ({
iCalUId: yyyyy (=the iCalUid I got from the creation of this event),
subject: "** Test Event Updated**",
body: {
contentType: "HTML",
content: "This is updated to 0800 .. 1000"
 },
start: {
dateTime: "2019-08-19T08:00:00",
timeZone: "UTC"
 },
 end: {
    dateTime: "2019-08-19T10:00:00",
     timeZone: "UTC"
},
location:{
     displayName:"Somewhere else"
 }
});
```

This gives error "The OData request is not supported"

Answer (score 0):

I already found it, use the id and not the iCalUid

Comment: Do you happen to know how we update a `Date` field. I am getting error poster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56343428/1232087).

Comment: Yes this works in the sandbox. 
But how do I retrieve the JSON response in my JavaScript?